# How to install Magento on a laptop?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

When I install Magento 2, it gives me 4 errors. One is in a xsl file, one in a intl file, one in a soap file and one in a sockets file.

How can I remove all these errors? Please tell me.

Comment: Sorry, your question is irrelevant.

Comment: Please update your question to include the errors and the steps to reproduce. In its current state your question is not actionable as there is no detail for anyone to provide advice.

Answer (score 1):

These are the extensions that you need to install for php. which operating system you are using ?

xsl file,
intl file , 
soap file 
and sockets file

**if you are using windows then use.**

1. Check php.ini file. This is normally under your xampp folder (Example D:\xampp\php)
2. Search like php_soap.dll;,php_xsl.dll,php_intl.dll each dll extension
3. removing the first ; character, to make it looks like

> extension=php_soap.dll
>
> extension=php_xsl.dll
>
> extension=php_intl.dll

4. Once done restart Apache server.

**if you are using ubuntu then use the following**

> apt-get install php7.0-intl
>   apt-get install php7.0-xsl